# A conjecture of Erdos on consecutive differences of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $d_k = p_{k + 1} - p_k$ be the difference between consecutive primes and define
\begin{equation}
e_k = \left\{\begin{array}{c l} 1 &, d_{k + 1} > d_k \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right. .
\end{equation}
In a paper of 1947 Erdos conjectured that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = 1} ^\infty \frac{e_k}{2^k}
\end{equation}
was irrational. What is the state of this conjecture and is there some hidden importance in that question or is it, as it appears to me, a random musing of little consequence?

Comment: In my opinion: no hidden importance, little consequence. But Erdös had a way of stating conjectures that very efficiently got to the heart of what exactly we don't understand. Here, for example, the question is asserting the nonexistence of a particular type of structure (periodicity) in the sequence of $e_k$s.

Comment: The problem is solved by recent work of Banks--Freiberg--Turnage-Butterbaugh. Using the method of Maynard--Tao, they show that the sequence of e_k's contains arbitrarily long runs of 0's, as well as arbitrarily long runs of 1's. Hence, the sum has a nonperiodic binary expansion and so represents an irrational number.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd seen that paper before but I'd forgotten it solved that question. There are just too many papers that "solve an old question of Erdos"!

Comment: The paper is here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.7003.pdf